# Rebuilding Hyper V after crash

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller

I am currently having an issue with our Domain Controller network environment which is on Hyper V. Basically the machine that was hosting the Hyper V has crashed. The problem is not with hard drive but with the corrupted hyper v file.

We have all the vhds and xml configuration files in separate partition. Plan is to make a fresh install of hyper v and reattach all virtual machine. My question is how to do this so that we can retain same DC network?

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't see any reason your Domain Controller would be affected. What do you mean by "corrupted hyper-v file"?

Comment: Sorry, My concern is that if I build a brand new hyper V server from scratch, could I be able to import/add my existing vhds to the new Hyper V server and rebuild my DC environment?

Comment: You can get the old VMs into Hyper-V, yes. It's not quite as easy as "importing" them because they weren't "exported" cleanly. Still not clear on why you're rebuilding your DC environment; where is the DC, where are your backups?

Comment: You really need to define "corrupted hyper-v file". Was it the guest file that got corrupted or the host/parent install that got corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your DC was is separate server and then I don't see the issue right away ...

Or I could be missing what exactly the problem is ?

besides that you "lost" your config of the Hyper-V Server itself I don't see any issue to the Vm's.

if they can access the network on which the domain is "live" then for them nothing will change.

again, I think i'm missing something here regarding what exactly the issue at hand is though.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, "the corrupted hyper v file" is the Hyper-V host system?

If your Hyper-V host has failed, its not the end of the world. When you have a new host setup, create a new VM, and instead of creating a new .vhd, point to the one you recovered. You won't be able to use any snapshots, though. Assuming the .vhd isn't corrupted, or the guest OS didn't freak out when it was abruptly powered down, it should come up.